# How to call a function in C

Tags: c, function

I'm trying to find out how to call a given function from main().

```
void initialize(struct word_pair word_table[], int size)
```

e.g. `initialize ( what, 5);`

I'm new to C and I think that have messed everything in my head.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you have posted so far, but presumably you are posting here because something isn't working. That could be that `what` isn't the right type of `thing`, or something else is wrong. If you get an error message, perhaps posting that as part of your question [use the "edit" button] would give us some idea...

Comment: The more complex C parameter declarations will drive you crazy.  Try to separate the complex parameter declaration nonsense from the basic concepts of calling methods and using pointers -- learn those basic concepts first and avoid the crazy stuff for a few more days.

Answer (score 2):

This is one example usage:

```
#define SIZE 10
struct word_pair word_tables[SIZE];

// Populate the elements of word_tables

initialize(word_tables, SIZE);
```

The `initialize()` function takes 2 arguments:

- an array of `struct word_pair`
- the size of the array.

In the example above, the variable `word_tables` is an array of size `SIZE`.

`SIZE` is a `macro` defined to be `10` in the above example, but you can change it according to your need.

Comment: It should be word_tables in the function call rather than &word_tables. It'd still work, but it's the wrong pointer type.

Comment: Yes you're right, updated. Though the code would logically work, the compiler throws a warning. :)

Comment: As written, this won't work as you can't call a function at the global scope -- the call needs to be inside some other function.